# AttributeError 'NarrateUpdate' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: django

I got an attribute error on my NarrateUpdate view. I want to edit/update a user submission from a form

Here's my views.py:

```
class NarrateUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Narrate
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'narrate_update_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('narrate-status')
    success_message = "Narration successfully updated"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        footer = FooterLinks.objects.all()
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['footer'] = footer
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

The urls.py

```
path('narration/<int:pk>/update/', NarrateUpdate.as_view(), name='edit-narration'),
```

And here's the models.py:

```
class Narrate(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('F', 'FOR REVIEW'),
        ('P', 'PASSED'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    status = models.CharField(
    max_length=25, choices=STATUS, default='for_review', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/narration/%i/" % self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "narration"
        verbose_name_plural = "narrations"
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you overriding the `get` method? If you want to add `footer` better to do it in [**`get_context_data()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method:

```
class NarrateUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Narrate
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'narrate_update_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('narrate-status')
    success_message = "Narration successfully updated"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NarrateUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['footer'] = FooterLinks.objects.all()
        return context
```